# how to customise weekend dates with differnt dates and with differnts hours in full calendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

I want to show calendar in month view with an row wise date eg: today date **2018-sep-05**,I would to show in calendar.

```
2018-9-05,
2018-9-12,
2018-9-19
2018-9-26,
```

As I have done in week view [jsfidddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0m6y9xtf/4/) in this is fine,
 I want to do same as weekday view [jsfidddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/7xkpmq08/15/), but, here comes my problem with dow, here dow is 3 means Wednesday,
I want to show 5,12,19,26 dates with same **dow** and in different **timings**. 
All I want to below timing should fit in calendar

```
sep05 07am - 09pm, 
sep12 08am - 14pm,
sep19 10am - 13pm,
```

Is their any way to make it or any trick way.

```
     var hiddenDaysObj = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
        hiddenDaysObj.splice(selDate.getDay(), 1);
  const calObj = {
          defaultView: 'settimana',
          defaultDate: this.cldDate,
          editable: true,
          selectable: true,
          eventLimit: true,
          allDaySlot: false,
          minTime: '07:00',
          maxTime: '22:00',
          slotDuration: '00:10:00',
          slotLabelInterval: '00:15:00',
          weekends: true,
          header: {
            left: '',
            center: '',
            right: '',
          },
          slotLabelFormat: [
            'h(:mm) a'
          ],
          viewRender: function (view, element) {
            const s = '<div class="appnt-pro-name"><h6>TIME</h6> </div>';
            element.find('.fc-axis:eq(1)').html(s);
          },

          views: {
            settimana: {
              type: 'agendaWeek',
              duration: {
                months: 1
              },
              title: 'agendaWeek',
              groupByResource: true,
              columnFormat: 'ddd M/D',
            },
          },
          resources: resources,
          events: events,
          select: select,
       hiddenDays: hiddenDaysObj,
          schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source'
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not possible to do that, you would have to write a completely custom view unfortunately. But with the view you've made, you are already able to show all the data which fits into those timings. What are you really trying to achieve? If you want to make all the other times outside those ranges unavailable for selection, then there are other ways to do that.

Comment: thanks for your reply ADyson, S i have brought the date in the calendar here Im trying to fit the time for jsfiddle2, as i have did for jsfidddle, in jsfiddle I can change the time to paticular date , but comes to jsfiddle2 Ican not change the time according to date

Comment: because when I change the time for **jsfiddle2** it show only 7am-9pm  for all dates ie, from sept 5,12,19,26 it is effect the 7am to 9pm times, I want to make it different time for that dates.

Comment: Ok sorry I think I understand better now. You're right, `dow` and `selectConstraint` is not going to work for you here, because it just repeats the same rule for every Wednesday. You might be better to try with `selectAllow` - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow . You can write a completely custom function to decide whether a selection is valid or not. That way if you keep your own array of the valid dates/times, you can check the selected start and end times against the valid ones to see if it's permitted or not.

Comment: Another option is to cover all the non-selectable areas with Background Events (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events) and then use `selectOverlap` (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap) to  set a rule that background events cannot be overlapped by new selections - there's actually an example of that in the selectOverlap documentation page.

Comment: tq **ADyson** for ur reply, can I get more details how to use it , by using selectAllow I can place only one date and time only from 1 dow i.e for sept5, reaming date I cant not put into that **selectAllow** , If u can provide little more info that would be really grateful  from you.

Comment: in selectAllow you can do anything you like, it's a function entirely of your own design. Please edit your question to include your attempt to use it, then maybe we can fix it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179632/discussion-between-mitukula-and-adyson).

Comment: Finally I have done with this https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events. I have pushed the date and time with in events. I have got according to my scenario and thanks  **@ADyson**

Comment: That's great, really glad you solved it. If you like, you should publish the solution here by writing an Answer. Then others can learn from it and also upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have done with this https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events I have pushed the date and time with in events. I have got according to my scenario and thanks @ADyson
here is the example  [finalresult jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xkpmq08/36/)

```
events.push({id:1,
color:"gray",
start:"2018-09-05T10:00",
end:"2018-09-05T19:00",
rendering:"inverse-background",
},{
id:1,
color:"gray",
start:"2018-09-12T08:00",
end:"2018-09-12T13:00",
rendering:"inverse-background",
});
```